# How to specify library flags for a catkin package

Tags: catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to migrate one of my rosbuild packages to catkin. I am trying to specify the CFLags and LFlags that used to be hardcoded in the manifest.xml, but have to be specified in catkin_package cmake macro.

As far as I understand it, the default Lflags are set to {PROJECT_NAME}/lib, how would I go about changing this to, say, {PROJECT_NAME}/lib64?

I know I can specify an include directory which works fine and I can specify which libraries to link against, but how do I specify where to look for those libraries, i.e. the path after the -L flag?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53424/how-to-specify-library-flags-for-a-catkin-package/) by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2121 on 2013-01-25

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rather than explicitly exposing the CFLAGS directly, you should use `catkin_package()` to export from within CMake any libraries or headers to packages which depend on you.

Can you post a link to your package or put your old manifest/CMakeLists.txt up on a gist.github.com?  With some more specifics I can show you exactly how this would work.

---

Originally posted by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) with karma: 1626 on 2013-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on 2013-02-05**:
@WilliamWoodall: basically, I am trying to write a wrapper package that downloads 3rd party code and builds it, like we used to be able to from plain Makefiles with the help of download/unpack/patch/build scripts. Not sure if it possible or recommended with catkin.

**Comment by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on 2013-02-05**:
I have a CMake equivalent to the old Makefile but I have trouble combining my current CMakelists contents with catkin stuff. Package in question is here: https://github.com/arebgun/dynamixel_motor_experimental/tree/master/gearbox.

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2013-02-05**:
@arebgun That is not recommended with catkin anymore.  You can continue to use rosbuild to accomplish this, but if you intend to release this package or depend on it with other catkin packages, then you'll need to follow our forthcoming 3rd-party recommendation. (recommendation will be a REP soon)

**Comment by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on 2013-02-05**:
Yes, I wanted to release the package and have the ability for other catkin packages to depend on it. Will wait for the REP to be published. Thanks!

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2014-06-08**:
Did anything come of this arebgun? I'm trying to fix gearbox linking for dynamixel_motor_experiemental as well, but my only hack is to use:
sudo ln -s /home/dave/ros/ws_clam/devel/lib/libflexiport.so /usr/lib/libflexiport.so